# When saving files build opens in sublime text 2

Tags: build, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am having this issue with sublime text.

Whenever I save a file with command S it opens my build.
I have set up my build to be Firefox, saved under Packages/User/Firefox.sublime-build
Opening up my build with command B still works but ever time I want to save a file it
also opens the build...

Comment: I suggest that you open your default and user keymaps files and search for the word `build` and see if any have been defined with super+s.  Also check your firefox keymap assignments for the same thing.  You are probably just overriding save with a build assignment.  A less likely scenario would be an `on_post_save` event listener plugin triggering a build -- perhaps unwittingly added by you because it looked like an interesting package.